# Google Maps API Click Point Marker (not custom)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I render a google map object, I see a bunch of "markers" with the names of places next to them. Most of them are square dots, but sometimes they have a wine glass for a bar or a cup of coffee for a Starbucks.

What are these points called?

How do I detect when they are clicked? A 'click' listener on the Map object does not run if one of these points are clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are "points of interest" (poi).

You can't detect when they are clicked, but you can "style" the map not to display them.

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/a5c3b4a73ef5cd8/89ae0edaed5b0be0?lnk=gst&q=hide+poi#89ae0edaed5b0be0) in the Google Maps API v3 goup for details.

[Enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4797)

Comment: I cheated and made an invisible rectangle whose bounds equaled the maps bounds, updated with the map's "bounds_changed" event. This worked for my particular case where I wanted to draw a happy little circle where the user clicked.